# Custom initial setup screen from my android application

Tags: android, configuration, screen, preferences

I want to create a screen that display only the first time for the initial user setup. I read that I can do this with "PreferenceActivity." But what I need is that the application initially requests data step by step, first your e-mail, on a second display another parameter, another parameter in a third screen, so on. my question is whether the best way to do this is to create an activity for each parameter, or there is only one way to generate activity that asks each parameter separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharePrefrence` for this. When your setup is completed then save a value(`setupValue` in my code) into `SharePrefrence`. and when check every time that value(`setupValue` in my code) when you launch application.

you can save it as:

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("your_setup_flag", false);
    editor.commit();
```

you can get it as:

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 boolean setupValue = sp.getBoolean("your_setup_flag", false);
```